# PHP: Create Unique Variables In A For Loop

Tags: php, loops, variables, for-loop

I was wondering if it is possible to create unique variables in a for loop using PHP. I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
$level_count = 6

for ($i=1; $i<=$level_count; $i++) {
    $level_ + $i = array();
}
```

I would like to end up with the variables $level_1, $level_2, $level_3, $level_4, $level_5 and $level_6. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Arrays have been invented to stop you from doing what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms I'm pretty new to PHP so I didn't know this approach was frowned upon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$level_count = 6

for ($i=1; $i<=$level_count; $i++) {
    $l = "level" . $i;
    $$l = array();
}
```

But Zerkms is right...

```
$arr = array(array(),array(),array(),array(),array(),array());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier if you use arrays for this. Try this one-liner:

```
$level_count = 6;

$array = array_fill_keys(array_map(function($index) {
                                       return 'level_' . $index;
                                   }, range(1, $level_count)), array());

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird thing (I have no idea why you want to use it), but, just for educational purposes...

```
$level_count = 6;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $level_count; $i++) {
    $name = 'level_' . $i;
    $$name = array();
}
```

Comment: killed me with 10 seconds :)

Comment: @Sebas I spent some time trying to explain why I wrote this code in the first place )))