# How to create and keep variables in a for-loop using arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've been trying to work with two for-loops to iterate through a multidimensional array and to assign the values to individual variables. However, it doesn't work, because it seems that I can't get the variables assigned to the data.

```
    $onepage = array
  (
  array("navbar",22,28,23,25), 
  array("presentation",15,13,23,23), 
  array("content",5,2,13,10), 
  array("footer",17,15,23,26) 
  );

      function presetter($selection) { //selection = onepage
          for($n=0;$n<=3;$n++){
              for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){

                        $rwcl =  $selection[$n][0];
                        $numb = $i -1;
                        ${$rwcl . $numb} = $selection[$n][$i]; //outputs navbar1 
                        $l = $rwcl . $numb;
                        $$l = $selection[$n][$i];

                        echo ${$rwcl . $numb}; //outputs variable navbarx


                        echo $rwcl;//output column name

                        echo $selection[$n][$i];
                        echo "<br>";
              }
          }

      } //<-- works!

      presetter($onepage);
echo $navbar1;
```

The output is always Type 8 - undefined variable.
I've tried several options, also the proposed solution here: [PHP: Create Unique Variables In A For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108040/php-create-unique-variables-in-a-for-loop), but without a positive result.

Probably some will say that what I do is not the sense of arrays. And yes, you are right. But would like solve it.

Maybe somebody knows how to get it done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating *statics variables* inside you function. When the function is done, the variables will be useless.

If you want to use them outside your function, you should create *global variables* or make this function return an output with all variables created (maybe an array?).

Here is a example of a global variable inside a function:

```
<?php
    function printIt() {
        global $x;
        $x = array(1,2,3);
    }

    printIt();
    var_dump($x);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: It works, Clyff. Thank you very much. As it should. I'd like to upvote your answer, but unfortunately my account is too young. So thanks again.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you are creating variables inside a function that is why there are not accessible outside a function. You need to create global variables to access them. Here is the code

```
$onepage = array
(
array("navbar", 22, 28, 23, 25),
array("presentation", 15, 13, 23, 23),
array("content", 5, 2, 13, 10),
array("footer", 17, 15, 23, 26));

function presetter($selection) { //selection = onepage
for ($n = 0; $n <= 3; $n++) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

        $rwcl = $selection[$n][0];
        $numb = $i - 1;
        $var = $rwcl . $numb;
        global $$var;
        $$var = $selection[$n][$i]; //outputs navbar1 
    }
}}
presetter($onepage);echo $navbar1;
```

Comment: Like Clyff's answer, works well. Thank you, Kittu. :-)